# Как узнать ip у raspberry pi 3

Tags: ip, raspberry-pi, ethernet, raspbian

Есть raspberry pi 3 на котором установлена ОС `Raspbian` К ней подключен провод ethernet как можно узнать айпи адрес raspberry без подключения монитора?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть 2 типа, если версия ОС десктопная, то нужно подключить монитор и там настроить все, если же версия серверная, то нужно создать сетевой мост и посмотреть через роутер или программу Advanced IP Scanner

Answer (score 1):

Зайти в админку роутера и там посмотреть все подключенные устройства.

Стандартные IP роутеров
192.168.0.1
192.168.100.1
192.168.1.1
10.0.0.1

Пароли зачастую стоят дефолтные, найти их можно в яндексе спокойно. Поисковый запрос: "Роутер <модель роутера> пароль от админки"

Comment: В том то и дело что там ничего нету

Comment: @Log1c0 В таком случае скрины, модель роутера

Comment: @Log1c0 А вы смотрите устройства, подключенные к wi-fi или вообще все?